# How to get file name and extension in android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app connected to firebase realtime database. When I am trying to get file path and extension by the following methods, it shows the different name and also show same thing for extension.

Method used to get filename and path:

```
fileUri = data.getData();
String path = fileUri.getLastPathSegment();
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
String extension  = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1);


StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child(messagePushID + "." + extension);

filepath.putFile(fileUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
    {
        if (task.isSuccessful())
        {

            Map messageDocBody = new HashMap();
            messageDocBody.put("message", task.getResult().toString());
            messageDocBody.put("name",path);
            messageDocBody.put("type",checker);
            messageDocBody.put("extension",extension);
            messageDocBody.put("to",messageReceiverID);
            messageDocBody.put("from",messageSenderID);
            messageDocBody.put("time",time);
            messageDocBody.put("date",date);
            messageDocBody.put("messageID",messagePushID);
```

[image: Database]

Comment: `fileUri = data.getData();` -- I am going to guess that `data` is an `Intent`. Where is this `Intent` coming from? What is the value of `fileUri`?

Comment: **data** comes from **onActivityResult**

Comment: What `Intent` did you use with `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: ` Intent intent = new Intent();`
            `    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`
               ` intent.setType("application/*");`
                `startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Document"), 123);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I solved the problem,
-I thing `fileUri.getLastPathSegment()` it's returning the content of the file.
Get File Name method :

1. I defined Cursor:

   ```
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri,null, null, null, null);
   ```
2. nameIndex:

   ```
    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String filename =  cursor.getString(nameIndex);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) to give you a `Uri` with a `content` scheme. Your code assumes that the `Uri` has a `file` scheme and represents a filesystem path.

There is no guaranteed way to get a display name for such a `Uri`, and there is no requirement that the display name be a filename with a file extension. The content that the user chooses might never have been a file in the first place. You are welcome to try passing the `Uri` to `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri`(), then calling `getName()` on that `DocumentFile`, to get a display name.

In terms of file extensions, in addition to trying to parse one out of the display name, you could call `getType()` on the `DocumentFile`, then use `MimeTypeMap` to try to get a file extension commonly associated with the MIME type of the content.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. What you mean with **DocumentFile** ?

Comment: Do you recommend any method to get files from device storage?

Comment: @OmarAmmura: "What you mean with DocumentFile ?" -- `DocumentFile` is [a Java class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile), available from a library as part of the Android SDK.